# Syntax error in template - ” - Unexpected “: “, expected one of: “}”

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, tiki-wiki

I wanted to embed a Javascript widget in the modules in TikiWiki. In HTML widgets in all CMS, the JS code is accepted, but the Tiki reports Syntax Error.

The code is so.

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-more-link="https://jobs.internetblogger.de" data-per-page="10" src="https://jobs.internetblogger.de/content-widget.js" async data-hide-button data-css=".az-jobs-list {width: 105%; margin: auto;}" data-hide-location></script>
```

And the syntax error looks like this.

```
Syntax error in template “3b7535cb97b637bf9c01cddb0202d9db5b95b4f0” on line 1 “
” - Unexpected “: “, expected one of: “}”
```

How can I fix it, because normally the JS widget works in other open source CMS, forums, wikis and blogs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is most certainly that `{` is a special character interpreted by by tikiwiki. There must be a way to escape it.

Comment: Thanks for the Hints @jcaron , i found a solution! I'm not a php developer, but try the square brace and see there it worked. Good that you gave me such hints. So I can finish this issue and the JS widget will be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Because Smarty templating engine uses curly brackets any JS containing them must be wrapped inside `{literal}...{/literal}` block in the Tiki modules.

Comment: Thank you, then I know now and can apply it in the next module integrations.